# EhLib DBGridEh Scrolling Troubles

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dbgrid

I use [**EhLib DBGridEh**](http://ehlib.com/ehlibdetail.htm#TDBGridhEh) in my application and I've troubles with highliting when I start scrolling it using Scrollbar.
If I don't select cell in the grid than highliting will work correctly.
But if I select cell and start scrolling using **ScrollBar** than there will be highlited only one cell instead of whole raw and previous raw will be highlited too.
These you can see on picture.
[image: Scrolling bug]

Just few weeks ago I have the same situation when I scrolled grid using mouse wheel. This issue I resolved by adding handling of application messages.

```
procedure TMainForm.AppEventHandlerMessage(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
var
   i: SmallInt;
begin
   if Msg.message = WM_MOUSEWHEEL then
   begin
     Msg.message := WM_KEYDOWN;
     Msg.lParam := 0;
     i := HiWord(Msg.wParam) ;
     if i > 0 then
       Msg.wParam := VK_UP
     else
       Msg.wParam := VK_DOWN;

     Handled := False;
   end;
end;
```

There is the full list of the properties that are enabled in my grid:
**Options**

1. dgEditing
2. dgTitles
3. dgIndicator
4. dgColumnResize
5. dgColLines
6. dgRowLines
7. dgTabs
8. dgAlwaysShowSelection
9. dgMultiSelect

**OptionsEh**

1. dghFixed3D
2. dghResizeWholeRightPart
3. dghHighlightFocus
4. dghClearSelection
5. dghMultiSortMarking
6. dghEnterAsTab
7. dghRowHighlight

Comment: I think you have `dgEditing` enabled what should override `dgRowSelect` because you cannot edit the whole row thus the cells are selected. Can you select the cell (not the whole row) even with the mouse ?

Comment: Yes,  I can. And `dgEditing` is enabled, but `dgRawSelect` is disabled.

Comment: I've just found very interesting properties of EhLib DbGridEh - AllowedSelections. There you can set next values `gstRecordBookmarks`, `gstRectangle`, `gstColumns`, `gstAll`. At first glance, scrolling works correctly.

Comment: Uhm, sorry for misleading you. I've overlooked you're using `DBGridEh`, thus my comments makes no sense for you.

Comment: This is too narrowly focused (very few Delphi developers use this grid) to be likely to get an answer here. I suggest you try the vendor forums for this component.

Answer (score 2):

It is a feature of the DBGridEh. If it have multiselected area it stop rowhighlighting to avoid misunderstanding between seleced area and highlighting cells of the current row.

DmitryB

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is very usefull. And as I understand to avoid this situation we must configure `AllowSelections` option =)